# HTTP Error failed

Tags: php, google-api, http-request

I'm using a Google PHP SDK to do uploads for my clients in their google Drive using the Google APIs Console.
Sometimes I get this error: HTTP Error: (0) Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:4002:c06::5f: Network is unreachable

Anybody know how to resolve it?

Comment: What does the failing code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client network can't resolve an IPV6 address. So it can't open the socket for send the HTTP request.

You can force IPV4 with

```
curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```